# itextsharp hyperlink a image and have it open in default viewer when picked

Tags: c#, image, hyperlink, itext

I have a pdf file created with itextsharp with images in the file. I would like to put a hyperlink in the file that if you pick the picture it will open that picture in a picture viewer. I can set a hyperlink to a web address but have no idea how to get it to open a file.  Below is the code, yes I know that c:\test.jpg is a bad hardcoded file name but it is just a test. When you click the picture it does nothing but I have no idea how to tell it what to do.

```
iTextSharp.text.Image pic =TextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(comment.examplePic);
pic.ScaleToFit(200f, 200f);
Chunk cImage = new Chunk(pic, 0, 0, false);
Anchor anchor = new Anchor(cImage);
anchor.Reference = "c:\\test.jpg";
doc.Add(pic);
doc.Add(anchor);
```

Comment: Which of the proposed solutions did you eventually use?

Answer (score 1):

A PDF is self-contained. This means that all the resources needed to show the PDF are (usually) stored inside the PDF (exceptions are for instance fonts that can be retrieved from the operating system).

When you have an image that is shown on a PDF page, the bytes of that image are stored in what we call an *Image XObject*. An *XObject* is an object that is external to the page, but that is stored as a separate object inside the PDF file.

You are asking to serve the image bytes stored inside this separate object to a viewer on the operating system. This is impossible. I don't know of any viewer that can take those bytes and somehow forward them to an image viewer.

I can think of three possible workarounds. I don't know if any of these workarounds is acceptable to you.

**1. Serve the image online**

You could put the image on a server and use the code you have in your snippet to link to that online image. Of course: this will only work if the person viewing the document is online and clicks OK when his viewer asks him if it's OK to link to a resources on the internet.

**2. Serve the image as an annotation**

In this case, you create an annotation for which you create an appearance that renders that same image XObject in the annotation layer (all annotations are shown on top of the page content). You can easily change the visibility status of an annotation to make it invisible (in your case, this would be the default status) or visible (in your case, this would be triggered by a JavaScript action when clicking the link).

There's an example of such an annotation here: [Advertisement](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=143). If you open [advertisement.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/advertisement.pdf), you see an image with a button that says "Close this advertisement". Once you click that, the status of the annotation will be changed to invisible. You could do something similar, but the other way round: click a link to make it visible instead of invisible.

This solution doesn't depend on an external viewer, the image is shown in the PDF viewer.

**3. Add the image as optional content**

Starting with PDF 1.5, PDF supports optional content. See for instance the [OptionalContentExample](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=268). In this example, we have some questions and answers, but the answers are not visible by default. See [layer_actions.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter15/layer_actions.pdf). There are links "on / off / toggle" to make the answers visible or invisible.

You could do the same with images: you could add them to a layer that is invisible by default, but that can be made visible if somebody clicks a link. However: this requires a viewer that supports OCG (optional content groups) and the actions to change the status of these OCGs. For instance: if you would try the [layer_actions.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter15/layer_actions.pdf) example in the PDF viewer in Chrome, it won't work, but if you download the PDF and open it in Adobe Reader, you'll see the behavior I described.

**Summarized:**

You are asking something that is impossible, but there are workarounds. Please post another question if you have chosen a workaround and you don't succeed in making that workaround word (but please take into account that not all viewers support every workaround).

Answer (score 1):

no offence but too much knowledge sometimes makes you ignorant of small things.

simple solution to this problem is here

http://kuujinbo.info/iTextSharp/imageAnchor.aspx

sample code that i implemented works like charm

```
        PdfPCell p1 = new PdfPCell();
        p1 = new PdfPCell();
        p1.Padding = 0;
        p1.Border = 0;
        PdfPTable nav = new PdfPTable(1);
        nav.WidthPercentage = 100;
        nav.SpacingAfter = 12;
        navbarImg.Annotation= new Annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, ur);
        p1.Image = navbarImg;
        nav.AddCell(p1);
        _doc.Add(nav);
```